# Function for comparing two dataframes and making new column with true/false

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am trying to make a script for automating some "boring stuff" aka. log compliance at my new intern workplace. My problem is as follows:

1. i need to make a function which takes two dataframes (expected data and factual data) and compare their values by specific rows.
2. Once this is done I need to make a column named "Compliance" which takes a bool i.e shows true or false whether the data are in compliance or not. I am a bit stuck, so some help would be very much appreciated.

THE DATAFRAMES ARE NOT IDENTICAL. BUT HOLDS SOME OF THE SAME VALUES:

I have tried using som loops to itterate through the df's but i lack some basic pythonian logic (and experience).

I've also tried pd.merge, and also np.where but i can't seem to find a decent solution

I was thinking something like:

```
def checkConsistency(df1, df2, rows):

    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        hostname = row['column name here']

        for index2, row2, in df2.iterrows():
            deviceName = row2['column name here']

    df = pd.merge(df1, how='inner', left_on=['index'], right_on[rows])
    df["Compliance"] = np.where( (df1.index[row]) == (df2.index[row2]), True, False)

    return df
```

expected output should be the relevant rows, and a new column "Compliance", with boolean values

Comment: And what error are you getting with your current code ?

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument", but i also think my logic is rather incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```
import pandas as pd

def checkConsistency(df1, df2, indexItem):
    listReturn = []
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        listReturn.append(df1.iloc[i,indexItem] == df2.iloc[i,indexItem])

    df1["Compliance"] = listReturn

    return df1

data = [1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = [1,1,2,4,5]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(checkConsistency(df,df2,0))
```

Comment: Thank you, Sylvian. I'm gonna try this out. I have a team huddle i a moment, so will return later with an answer, whether the code works!

Comment: I just tried ypur solutuon, which gave me an idea of how to solve the problem, so i am going accept it as a valid answer. Again, thank you for your time!